# How to create horizontal recycle view with only text?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make a horizontal recyclerview in my Android application so I see a of tutorials to make it, its very complicated because I don't want to add images or on click listeners I just have a card and textView inside it and I want to add an id to every single item I have some background about that below

This is my activity of recyclerview items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#000"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_data_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Test"
            android:textColor="#38ef7d"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingStart="18dp"
            android:paddingEnd="18dp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I created a class named RecyclerViewAdapter.

I will add this RecyclerView to a named activity called SettingsActivity.java

Any ideas?

Comment: All clues point to the layout manager

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use LinearLayoutManager in your RecyclerView, then you can pass true as to third argument in the LinearLayoutManager constructor.

For example:

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
            LinearLayoutManager(
                this,
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                true
            )
        )
```

Comment: this is code i get from android studio developers page i created RecyclerViewAdapter and RecyclerViewHolder and now i have a problem i commented it bellow in the code  `mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(what to do here);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`

Answer (score 0):

change RelativeLayout width and height

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and Remove this line android:orientation="vertical"

and 
 `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
            LinearLayoutManager(
                this,
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                true
            )
        )`

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal scrolling in recycler view set the layout manager for recyclerview as:

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Hope this should help.

Comment: thanks sir, but i have a problem now i have to set this `mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(myDataset);` but there is no option for **myDataset**

Comment: ok, so this code is just for horizontal scrolling. for the dataset you have to create your own dataset like an array of string and pass this array to your adapter then get the string from the array and set it to your textview in onbindviewholder() method of adapter